# Bootstrap, no links or buttons work on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The only links that work are the ones in the navbar, no other links or buttons work.

Normal links don't work, Guess(tied to js event) doesn't work, form submit buttons don't work...

The only libraries I have called are bootstrap and jquery.

What's going on?

Comment: cannot get any answer , we dont know whats going on in your css and ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your HTML structure is valid. You can use the [Bootstrap Basic Template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) to manage the script and CSS imports.
2. Make sure the CSS elements in the divisions are correct, make sure that there are no typing/spelling problems in the parent elements, they can ruin whats inside (CSS wise).
3. What do you mean links "Don't work"? Are the're not clickable or they look like default CSS?